OLE DB Provider for ODBC SQL Server
I have a Windows 2019 server with SQL Server 2019. I am trying to set up a linked server that will use odbc (mysql). When I try to create a new linked server, there is no provider with odbc. How do add the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC?
I have searched Microsoft and other sites, investigated Visual Studio and SQL Server tools.

Which providers are available?

Ole Provider for sql server integration services
sql native client 11.0
microsoft ofice 12.0 access databse services
microsoft ole db driver for sql server
microsoft ole db provider for search
microsoft ole db provider for analysis services 14.0
microsoft ole db simple provider
